# Is there a way to have Word autolink custom protocols?

Tags: ms-word

I've written a very small app that handles the custom `bug:` protocol by opening the correct page in a web browser. For instance:

```
<a href="bug:88451">#88451</a>
```

This link brings up the bug tracker at the page of bug id 88451. (It also handles `bug://88451` for 'compatibility' purposes.)

However, it's only half-useful if people have to manually add hyperlinks to it.

We use Outlook 2003, which in turn uses Word 2003 as its text editor. When you write `http://foo.com/` in Outlook/Word (which I'll now refer as to 'Word' only), it automatically adds a hyperlink to `http://foo.com/`.

So, if I write `bug:88451`, or even `bug://88451` if it's easier in Word, is there a way to have Word to autolink it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Registering custom url protocl handler that Outlook recognizes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881592/registering-custom-url-protocl-handler-that-outlook-recognizes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881592/registering-custom-url-protocl-handler-that-outlook-recognizes) similar SO post helps, it contains a link to [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914) which should point you in the right direction.

Comment: You're right, my question is a duplicate. Should have checked better.