# WPF application - create custom hyperlinks

Tags: wpf, hyperlink, registry

We are developing a WPF application and we have a requirement that a user can open certain screen and they need an option to create link and then paste them outside of the application like outlook or Skype etc... Once they paste it should appear as a link and when they click on the link it should open the application and navigate to the screen for which the link was created.
To achieve this we are trying to create a custom links like appname://, and on clicking we are trying to open the application and pass the guid as parameter.
Can you point us on how to create custom links and map them to navigate to particular exe on clicking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to register your own URI Scheme in the registry and link it to your application executable path

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT


alert
      (Default) = "URL:Alert Protocol"
      URL Protocol = ""
      DefaultIcon
         (Default) = "alert.exe,1"
      shell
         open
            command
               (Default) = "C:\Program Files\Alert\alert.exe" "%1"
```

[You can read more on it here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85))

Comment: This solves 50% of the problem, but I don't see them shown as link.  For ex: mailto:dd@bn.com if I paste this in outlook / word, it appears as link and on clicking it opens outlook, how can achieve that behavior?

Comment: @user3202694 Each application has how it interprets URI and handles them. Outlook, Skype, etc. You'll have to build a workaround for each application you want to interpret your URI. Take a look at this for outlook: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881592/registering-custom-url-protocl-handler-that-outlook-recognizes?rq=1