# Xamarin (Android/iOS) Deep Linking - Opening App via URL (custom or not)

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, deep-linking, custom-url

I have made a web with Sharepoint and Office365, and an app with Xamarin for Android and iOS. Users recieve notifications in their emails, with some URLs from my web attached to it. When opening these URLs from the mobile, I want to open them into the app, but I have gone through lots of problems to implement that.

I know that there are 2 ways of opening links, implementing deep linking with Universal Links(iOS) - App Links(Android) or using custom URL schemes.

- When trying to implement custom URL schemes I've found out that Outlook, Gmail and other email apps don't recognize what a custom link is, and display the custom link as a simple text, so links are unclickable in the mobile. So example://something it is not clickable from the email. Any ideas on how to solve this?
- When trying to implement Universal Links(iOS), you need to upload an AASA(apple-app-site-association) file to your domain, which has to be located either in the root of your domain or in a ./well-known/ folder. The problem is that you can't place files on these location when having a web made with Sharepoint and Office365. Support from apple has told me that the only solution is to change the web, which in my case it is not posible.

I've only managed to implement opening links from an email with my app for Android using intent-filters. This work fine, but I need to open the same link in Android an iOS.

I can change the format of the link that it is sent in an email from https://mywebbexample.com to myapp://example.com , that isn't a problem.

Any idea on how to proceed?

Thank you.

Comment: The only way I managed to solve this was by registering a customURL that Outlook detects as a hyperlink. I found those prefixes here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/934504/10097791

We registered the custom scheme in Android/iOS for wais://example.com and it is perfectly working. I know it's a workaround, but it's the first working solution after weeks of investigation.

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to copy from the first source. Here's how you register a Uri Scheme at [xamarinhelp.com](https://xamarinhelp.com/uri-scheme/), Examples on how you create [launch mobile app by url](https://xamarinhelp.com/launching-mobile-app-via-uri-scheme/) example:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
    Xamarin.Forms.Device.OpenUri(new Uri("skype://555-1111"));
});
```

Custom schemes are filtered by Gmail etc, so you  might be able to do it by:

```
<a href="my-app://deep-link" href="https://example.com/?link=123" href="my-app://deep-link">Open in app</a>
```

If you use a regular https link, separate Android and iOS devices by user-agent, then redirect with a 301 or 302 HTTP Redirect to my-app://deep-link. Or the Android version if its user-agent. I am doing this at work and it works fine, so it should for you too?

Comment: That's not what I'm asking, maybe I haven't explained myself correctly. I don't need my app to open another app via and url displayed inside my app. I need my app to be opened with external links from other apps(Gmail, Outlook, etc) or browser version of that apps.

Comment: You still need to register the uri to tell Android / iOS it is your app? From a mail you should use a normal url to your API and then from the API send a redirect (301/302) to the correct one?

Comment: Just in the case you want to work with custom URL. In that case, yes, you need to register the uri (on Manifest for Android and Inflo.plist for iOS). Again, I don't have a problem in doing so, I have a problem with the display of the url in the email (not my app), which is not clickable when using custom URL.

Comment: Yes, and to that I told you to send a https link in your newsletters / emails.

Comment: If I send and https link in my newsletters/emails I can only open them with Android, not iOS. For iOS, you can't register https as custom URL in the info.plist